# Как оптимизировать данный код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте,
Есть 2 блока, хочется чтоб .workDataHeight блок брал высоту .work-block.
Написал следующее, подскажите пожалуйста как оптимизировать(ведь делается одно и тоже):

```
    var workDataHeightRel = $('.workDataHeight').attr('rel');
    var workBlockRel = $('.work-block').attr('rel');

    if (workBlockRel = 1) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="1"]').height($('.work-block[rel="1"]').height());
    }
    if(workBlockRel = 2) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="2"]').height($('.work-block[rel="2"]').height());
    }
    if(workBlockRel = 3) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="3"]').height($('.work-block[rel="3"]').height());
    }
    if(workBlockRel = 4) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="4"]').height($('.work-block[rel="4"]').height());
    }
    if(workBlockRel = 5) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="5"]').height($('.work-block[rel="5"]').height());
    }
    if(workBlockRel = 6) {
        $('.workDataHeight[rel="6"]').height($('.work-block[rel="6"]').height());
    }
```

Так только первый блок отрабатывает:

```
$(".workDataHeight[rel ="+ workDataHeightRel +"]").height($(".work-block[rel ="+ workBlockRel +"]").height());
```

Вот весь пример с html, css и js:

```js
var workDataHeightRel = $('.workDataHeight').attr('rel');
var workBlockRel = $('.work-block').attr('rel');

if (workBlockRel = 1) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="1"]').height($('.work-block[rel="1"]').height());
}
if(workBlockRel = 2) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="2"]').height($('.work-block[rel="2"]').height());
}
if(workBlockRel = 3) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="3"]').height($('.work-block[rel="3"]').height());
}
if(workBlockRel = 4) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="4"]').height($('.work-block[rel="4"]').height());
}
if(workBlockRel = 5) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="5"]').height($('.work-block[rel="5"]').height());
}
if(workBlockRel = 6) {
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="6"]').height($('.work-block[rel="6"]').height());
}
```

```css
#work{padding:50px;background-color:#eee}#work .work-block{margin-bottom:60px}#work .work-block:last-child{margin-bottom:0px}#work .work-block .workDataHeight{padding:0px !important}#work .work-block .work-data{height:100%;color:#34495e;position:relative}#work .work-block .work-data::before{content:" ";position:absolute;top:46px;left:50%;bottom:46px;width:1px;margin-left:-1.5px;background-color:#34495e}#work .work-block .work-data p{margin:0px;font-family:"RobotoBold",sans-serif}#work .work-block .work-data .data-top{position:absolute;top:20px;width:100%}#work .work-block .work-data .data-bottom{position:absolute;bottom:20px;width:100%}#work .work-block .work-text{height:100%;padding:20px 20px}#work .work-block .work-text h4{font-family:"RobotoBold",sans-serif}#work .work-block .work-text a{color:#f15324}#work .work-block .work-text p{margin:10px 0 0 0}#work .work-block-inverse .work-text{text-align:right}#brand{height:200px !important}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="work">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        
        <div class="row">

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="1">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="1">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://corp.megafon.ru/about/megafon/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="2">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="" class="link-disabled" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex<br>ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="2">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="3">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="3">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://bcc.ru/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="4">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://www.gkefesk.ru/" class="" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="4">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="5">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="5">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://tddomovoy.ru/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="6">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11 ">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://www.peterlink.ru/" class="" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex<br>ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="6">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

или **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7544zxs/1/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно одной <strike>таблэтки</strike> строчки в цикле

```
$('.workDataHeight').each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).closest('.work-block').height());
});
```

**[closest](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)** - Ближайший подходящий предок. Т.е. Для каждого из **выбранных элементов**, `closest()` будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель, и так далее, до начало дерева DOM.

Comment: Вы попробовали на jsfiddle эту строчку применить?  Я так уже пробовал по разному крутить, все равно либо только для первого блока применяется, либо совсем не работает.  Попробуйте пожалуйста, у меня не выходит.

Comment: @SilaevD попробуйте через цикл. посмотрите еще раз ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Циклом можно сделать

```js
for(var i = 0; i < $('.work-block').length; i++){
  $('.workDataHeight[rel="'+i+'"]').height($('.work-block[rel="'+i+'"]').height());
};
```

```css
#work{padding:50px;background-color:#eee}#work .work-block{margin-bottom:60px}#work .work-block:last-child{margin-bottom:0px}#work .work-block .workDataHeight{padding:0px !important}#work .work-block .work-data{height:100%;color:#34495e;position:relative}#work .work-block .work-data::before{content:" ";position:absolute;top:46px;left:50%;bottom:46px;width:1px;margin-left:-1.5px;background-color:#34495e}#work .work-block .work-data p{margin:0px;font-family:"RobotoBold",sans-serif}#work .work-block .work-data .data-top{position:absolute;top:20px;width:100%}#work .work-block .work-data .data-bottom{position:absolute;bottom:20px;width:100%}#work .work-block .work-text{height:100%;padding:20px 20px}#work .work-block .work-text h4{font-family:"RobotoBold",sans-serif}#work .work-block .work-text a{color:#f15324}#work .work-block .work-text p{margin:10px 0 0 0}#work .work-block-inverse .work-text{text-align:right}#brand{height:200px !important}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="work">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        
        <div class="row">

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="1">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="1">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://corp.megafon.ru/about/megafon/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="2">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="" class="link-disabled" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex<br>ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="2">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="3">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="3">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://bcc.ru/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="4">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://www.gkefesk.ru/" class="" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="4">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block clearfix" rel="5">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="5">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://tddomovoy.ru/" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="work-block work-block-inverse clearfix" rel="6">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11 ">
              <div class="work-text">
                <h4>text</h4>
                <a href="http://www.peterlink.ru/" class="" target="-blank">text</a>
                <p class="text-muted">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex<br>ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt<br>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 workDataHeight" rel="6">
              <div class="work-data text-center">
                <p class="data-top">text</p>
                <p class="data-bottom">text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Супер! пробовал через $.each сделать, не получилось..а это то что нужно.  Только для последнего блока не отрабатывает.  lenght не точно отрабатывает?

Comment: Госпадя..до меня как до жирафа.. поставил меньше или равно, все работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @SilaevD, мда :D